# How to forward/proxy WebSocket with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, next.js

My app is split into two parts. The NextJS front end and a separate Spring Boot GraphQL API backend.

Let's say the NextJS server is https://a.com/ and the Spring Boot server is https://b.com/

How would go about forwarding all requests for https://a.com/graphql to https://b.com/graphql INCLUDING WebSocket stuff, since GraphQL uses WebSockets for it's *subscriptions* functionality.

I know that you can set up rewrites in `next.config.js` like this

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/graphql',
        destination: 'https://b.com/graphql',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

But I have no idea if this method also supports WebSockets or not.

Answer (score 1):

create and run nextjs with ur own proxy server.

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import express from "express";
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";
import next from "next";
import { Environment } from "./src/utils/environment";

const { port, backendHost } = Environment;
const backendPort = 5000;
const target = `http://${backendHost}:${backendPort}`;
const app = next({ dev: true, hostname: "localhost", port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(
      "/graphql",
      createProxyMiddleware({
        target,
        pathRewrite: { "^/graphql": "/graphql" },
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        ws: true,
      })
    );
    server.use(
      "/api",
      createProxyMiddleware({
        target,
        pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" },
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        ws: false,
      })
    );
    server.all(/^\/_next\/webpack-hmr(\/.*)?/, async (req, res) => {
      handle(req, res);
    });
    server.all("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));
    server.listen(port, () => console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`));
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("Error:::::", err));
```